# How to split my JSON object in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create pagination for my table that lists the objects returned from my DB as an object.  My data structure will look something like:

```
$scope.myJSONObj = {
    app1: {
      id: 1,
      appName: "appIntegrated1",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    app2: {
      id: 2,
      appName: "appIntegrated2",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    app3: {
      id: 3,
      appName: "appIntegrated3",
      status: "Completed"
    },
    app4: {
      id: 4,
      appName: "appIntegrated4",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    app5: {
      id: 5,
      appName: "appIntegrated5",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    app6: {
      id: 6,
      appName: "appIntegrated6",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    app7: {
      id: 7,
      appName: "appIntegrated7",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    app8: {
      id: 8,
      appName: "appIntegrated8",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    app9: {
      id: 9,
      appName: "appIntegrated9",
      status: "Pending"
    },
    app10: {
      id: 10,
      appName: "appIntegrated10",
      status: "Pending"
    }
```

I am trying to split my structure in half, and display the first five results.  I have a prev/next button, and when I click next, it should display the next 5 results (in this case the last 5).  However, for everything to work, I need to be able to split my object, and so far every method I've researched involves arrays, and objects requiring some hack.  I was wondering if I was missing something, or I have to create a solution to work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure JavaScript :

```
function getEntries(from, to) {
    var entries = [];
    for(var key in myJSONObj) {
        // extract index after `app`
        // var index = key.substring(3);
        // Better way : extract index using regular expression, so it will match `something1`, `foo2`, `dummy3`
        var index = parseInt(key.replace( /^\D+/g, ''));

        if(index >= from && index <= to) {
            entries.push(myJSONObj[key]);
        }
    }
    return entries;
}

console.log(getEntries(0, 5));
```

Comment: I didn't see that it wasn't an array, as the root object @stej4n you have a great answer. +1

Comment: Edit: a better way to extract index is to use regular expression, so it will match `something1`, `foo2`, `dummy3` ;)

Comment: this is not a perfect solution. it will fail if there is no number in key. eg:  {a:{x:1,y:2},b:{x:1,y:2},c:{x:1,y:2},d:{x:1,y:2}}

Comment: You are right, a default index (0 for example) can be defined like this :  `key.replace( /^\D+/g, '') || 0`

Comment: @ajaiJothi for my app, I can be sure that there will be an int key, but I see your point.

Comment: @user3334871 can you look at my solution in answers

Answer (score 1):

**Try _.chunk**

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chunk

```
$scope.pages = _.chunk($scope.myJSONObj,5);

$scope.getPage = function( pageIndex ){
return $scope.pages[pageIndex];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Sorry, I'm working in a business setting, and am unable to use third party solutions.  Without looking at the link, is _.chunk native to Angular?  I tried locally and it didn't work.

Comment: This is because _.chunk works with Arrays not Objects. You have to use _.pick(object, ['app1', 'app2', 'app3',...]);

Comment: Hi @stej4n, could you expand on that in an answer?  I'm not sure what you mean.  I want to create pagination on objects that I won't be sure what the values coming back are, so I can't hard-code 'app1', 'app2', etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's untested - but I wrote a chunk method for you in vanilla JS since you can't use lodash.

```
    function chunk(obj, chunkSize) {
        var resultArray = [];
        var resultArrayCurrentIndex = 0;
        for (var key in obj) {

            var item = obj[key];
            if (resultArray[resultArrayCurrentIndex].length <= chunkSize) {
                if (!resultArray[resultArrayCurrentIndex]) {
                    resultArray[resultArrayCurrentIndex] = [item];
                } else {
                    resultArray[resultArrayCurrentIndex].push(item)
                }
            } else {
                resultArrayCurrentIndex++
                resultArray[resultArrayCurrentIndex] = [item];
            }
        }

        return resultArray;

    }
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
$scope.pages = chunk(yourObject, 5);
$scope.getPage = function(index){
return $scope.pages[index];
}
```

EDIT - changed it to accept an obj.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll take a look at your answer in a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Used `Object.keys`, `Array.prototype.slice` and `Array.prototype.reduce` to solve your issue. Hope this helps

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.myJSONObj = {"app1":{"id":1,"appName":"appIntegrated1","status":"Pending"},"app2":{"id":2,"appName":"appIntegrated2","status":"Pending"},"app3":{"id":3,"appName":"appIntegrated3","status":"Completed"},"app4":{"id":4,"appName":"appIntegrated4","status":"Pending"},"app5":{"id":5,"appName":"appIntegrated5","status":"Pending"},"app6":{"id":6,"appName":"appIntegrated6","status":"Pending"},"app7":{"id":7,"appName":"appIntegrated7","status":"Pending"},"app8":{"id":8,"appName":"appIntegrated8","status":"Pending"},"app9":{"id":9,"appName":"appIntegrated9","status":"Pending"},"app10":{"id":10,"appName":"appIntegrated10","status":"Pending"}};

$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 5;
$scope.totalPage = Math.ceil( Object.keys($scope.myJSONObj).length/$scope.pageSize);
//pageNumber starts from 0 here
$scope.goToPage = function(pageNumber) {
  pageNumber = pageNumber>=0?pageNumber:0;
  var from = pageNumber*$scope.pageSize;
  var to = from + $scope.pageSize;
  return Object.keys($scope.myJSONObj).slice(from,to).reduce(function(a,b){
    a[b] = $scope.myJSONObj[b];
    return a;
  },{});
};

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
<button ng-disabled="currentPage===0" ng-click="currentPage = currentPage - 1">prev</button>
<button ng-disabled="currentPage===totalPage-1" ng-click="currentPage = currentPage + 1">next</button>
<b>Page: {{currentPage+1}}/{{totalPage}}</b>
<pre>{{goToPage(currentPage) | json}}</pre>
</div>
```